# Wildcard Help for find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of these records in a text file:

```
ROESImageCameraMake=�iP{��!-T�x0�
ROESImageCameraModel=��O�W�

ROESImageCameraMake=��%.Bph�����
ROESImageCameraModel=�d�
```

Notice that the value is different in every case (all 1000+ entries).  I need to do a find and replace in Notepad++ to give me this:

```
ROESImageCameraMake=Nikon
ROESImageCameraModel=D100
```

I am not familiar with Regex.

Comment: How are we supposed to extract `Nikon` from `�iP{��!-T�x0�`? Or is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: This file was corrupted, and I just need to replace the crazy characters with basically anything.

Comment: Normally I can do a find and replace because the crazy characters are the same throughout the document, but not in this case.

Comment: It looks like it need to get rid of more:  Is there a way to replace this:

Text=
ROESImageCameraMake=�rs��N`�>�
�$J�
ROESImageCameraModel=q� �d�
PackageID=

with

Text=
PackageID

Comment: edit your question please

Comment: This basically has nothing to do with regexp. It does not seem to form a regular grammar, or a similar binary code (for which regexps are not the best choice to begin with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find**: `ROESImageCameraMake=.*`
**Replace**: `ROESImageCameraMake=Nikon`

Make sure to tick "Regular expression" at the bottom.
This is based on your comment that you want to replace random junk with ***always*** `Nikon`